# How does one merge tags?

Tags: discussion, support

There are numerous entries under "colonization" and only four under "colonisation" which is just a different spelling. How would one merge the four "orphan" posts under the larger heading?

Answer (score 2):

[Vote to mark them as synonyms.](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags/colonization/synonyms)

[image]